# Trouble with validate() on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have html like these

```
<form class="form-filter" id="form-filter-excel" role="form">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-5">
                    <label>Date range</label>
                    <div class="input-group input-daterange datepicker">
                        <input id="fRange" name="fRange" class="form-control input-sm" type="text">
                        <span class="input-group-addon bg-primary">to</span>
                        <input id="sRange" name="sRange" class="form-control input-sm" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-1">
                    <label>
                        &nbsp;
                    </label>
                    <a class="btn btn-wide btn-primary form-control" href="#" id="btnexport" ><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> Export To Excel</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

end here my screen shoot
[image]

My question i wanna use validate() on jquery, but i'm kinda stuck i wanna use `class= "input-daterange"` as field, and the input fRange and sRange as required. How do i did that, if i using fRange and sRange as field, the error massage show up mess.  Any idea??

UPDATE :
Sorry for not unclear my question
I'm using jquery validate like these

```
$('#form-filter-excel').validate({
            highlight: function(element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').prop('required',true);
            },
            unhighlight: function(element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').prop('required',false);
            },
            errorElement: 'span',
            errorClass: 'help-block',
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            },
            rules: {
                fRange: {
                    required: true,
                    date: true
                },
                sRange: {
                    required: true,
                    date: true
                }
            },
             messages: {
                fRange: "Please insert these input",
                sRange: "Please insert these input"
            },
        });

        $('#btnexport').click(function() {
            $('#form-filter-excel').valid();

            if($('#form-filter-excel').valid()==true)
            {
                var Fod = $('#fRange').val();
                var Tod = $('#sRange').val();

                window.open(host+"ajax/excelpoinfo?Fod=" + Fod +"&Tod=" + Fod, '_blank'); 
            } 
        });
```

but the problem is the error massage not show under my input but show error like these on my screen
[image]

What i need is the error massage show on under each my input.

UPDATE:
I change my mind, i'm using sweet alert then, tq for helping. And for  Mayank Pandeyz, u didnt see my question clearly, like i said, that not helping, even u said change replacement. Still not work.

Comment: Very unclear about what you need.

Comment: Clearly explain what you want to achieve

Comment: I edit my question, for clearly, i wanna make error massage is show up (placing) in under each my input.

Answer (score 0):

On both the textbox provide the name attribute with its values like:

```
<form id="frmDetails" name="frmDetails">
  <input type="textbox" name="fRange">
  <input type="textbox" name="sRange">
</form>
```

And put the validation code on these like:

```
$('#frmDetails').validate({
    rules:
    {
        fRange: {
            required: true
        },
        sRange: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages:
    {
        fRange: {
            required: "Please select fRange"
        },
        sRange: {
            required: "Please select sRange"
        }
    }
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cubttgow/26/)

Comment: my html is diferent with yours, so if i'm using u're code jquery, the error massage not in the place. I'm edit my question, and u see my image the position error massage not in place.

Comment: Check my fiddle, in which there are two error message labels, you can put these labels where ever you want the error messages

Comment: Seems u not understanidng what i'm said, i'm using plugins datepcikter and u didnt see my code html?? I'm using input-group input-daterange datepicker, in your code is not working for my code.

Comment: Remove the error placement part from validate function and try my fiddle code, it will definitely work